# Transformation Matrices in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, transform, matrix-multiplication

Allright, I'm kind of stumped here. I'm working on a 2D game that has planets that orbit other bodies, and rotate along their axis as well. I decided to use Matrices because I hated how clunky I had to make thing otherwise. The issue is now that I would like to be able to focus on a certain part of the surface and be able to track it. Here's the code so far:

Planet.UpdateMatrix():

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates the transformation matrix
/// </summary>
private void UpdateMatrix()
{
    rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY((float)(state.PlanetAngle * (Math.PI / 180D)));

    if (settings.OrbitPlanet == null) 
    {
        transform =
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(
            new Vector3(
                    (float)extraMath.lengthdir_x(state.OrbitAngle * (Math.PI / 180D), settings.OrbitDistance),
                    (float)0,
                    (float)extraMath.lengthdir_y(state.OrbitAngle * (Math.PI / 180D), settings.OrbitDistance)
                    ));
    }
    else
    {
        transform =
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(
                new Vector3(
                    (float)extraMath.lengthdir_x(state.OrbitAngle * (Math.PI / 180D), settings.OrbitDistance),
                    (float)0,
                    (float)extraMath.lengthdir_y(state.OrbitAngle * (Math.PI / 180D), settings.OrbitDistance)
                    ))
            * settings.OrbitPlanet.Transform;
}
}
```

and the Planet.Draw:

```
/// <summary>
/// Draws this planet
/// </summary>
/// <param name="device">The graphics device to draw with</param>
/// <param name="view">The ViewParameters to use</param>
public void Draw(GraphicsDevice device, ViewParamaters view)
{
    effect.View = view.View;
    effect.Projection = view.Projection;
    effect.World = view.World  *  TotalTransform; //TotalTransform is rotation * translation

    draw stuff...
```

But what I need is this in the Game.Update:

```
//Handle surface tracking
if (TrackSurface)
{
    view.World = ???;
}
```

I'd like to be able to just set a world transform to have it draw all nice and centered and rotated and such.

Pics:
[image: Planet]
[image: Solar System]
Can anyone give me a hand with this? Is it even possible?

UPDATE: I now have the planet tracking working for a specific planet, but the other planets in the system do not change accordingly.

For instance, say I track the next planet from the sun, the view tracks the surface, but the sun stays still (should technically rotate around planet to simulate the planet still turning along it's own axis and orbiting star)

As well, if I try to apply a rotation, such as tracking the planet's surface at a specific angle, All the other planets rotate along their own axis instead of around the planet I'm tracking.

New Code:

```
view.World = Matrix.Invert(TargetPlanet.TotalTransform *
    Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians((float)SurfaceOffset)));
```

Comment: So you want to set the inverse of the planet's `TotalTransform`?

Comment: Hmm. It tracks the planet well doing that, but say I track planet 2, the planet's origin planet (i.e the sun) does not move (it should if we're tracking the surface)...

Comment: Then you could try `effect.World = TotalTransform * view.World`.

Comment: Well, now the planet moves but the view doesn't track it. Facepalm. :P